# Apache con Xampp no inicia por puertos bloqueados

Tags: apache, seguridad, xampp

**Detalle del log:**

```
13:41:13  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
13:41:13  [main]    Windows Version:  Pro  64-bit
13:41:13  [main]    XAMPP Version: 7.0.8
13:41:13  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
13:41:13  [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
13:41:13  [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
13:41:13  [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
13:41:13  [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
13:41:13  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "d:\xampp\"
13:41:13  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
13:41:13  [main]    All prerequisites found
13:41:13  [main]    Initializing Modules
13:41:13  [Apache]  Problem detected!
13:41:13  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
13:41:13  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:41:13  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:41:13  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
13:41:13  [Apache]  Problem detected!
13:41:13  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "E:\vmware\vmware-hostd.exe -u "C:\ProgramData\VMware\hostd\config.xml"" with PID 4128!
13:41:13  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:41:13  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:41:13  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
13:41:13  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
13:41:13  [main]    Control Panel Ready
13:41:16  [Apache]  Problem detected!
13:41:16  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
13:41:16  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:41:16  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:41:16  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
13:41:16  [Apache]  Problem detected!
13:41:16  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "E:\vmware\vmware-hostd.exe -u "C:\ProgramData\VMware\hostd\config.xml"" with PID 4128!
13:41:16  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:41:16  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:41:16  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
13:41:16  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
13:41:16  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
13:41:18  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
13:41:18  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:41:18  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:41:18  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:41:18  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:41:18  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:41:18  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
13:41:18  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Puerto 80 [image: log del apache el proceso pid 4]

¿cómo lo puedo solucionar si es un proceso del sistema?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18300377/1983854

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para cerrar los procesos que estan usando esos puertos, puedes usar la herramienta de microsoft **[TCPVIEW](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)**, que te da una lista detallada de los procesos que se están ejecutando y los puertos que cada proceso esta usando.

Busca el proceso que esta usando el puerto 80 y 443 en la lista que te aparecerá y luego das click derecho en ese proceso y eliges finalizar proceso, ten cuidado al cerrar procesos ya que pueden estar siendo utilizados por el sistema y podrías causar algun daño.

El uso del puerto 80 en windows puede ser por el servicio de publicación de world wide web **(World Wide Web Publishing Service)** de IIS si no tienes nada corriendo en IIS puedes desactivarlo sin problema, mira en los servicios de windows si esta corriendo este servicio y detenlo o desactivalo.

Comment: gracias juan pinzon he desactivado el servicio de IIS y el puerto 80 ya esta libre, ya tengo el apache funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Creo que [esta respuesta](http://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/puerto-80-ocupado-por-sistema-y-memoria-comprimida/85573441-9fdf-4645-9934-10d6520e948f?auth=1#LastReply) de Microsoft Answers puede serte de ayuda. Te explica como cambiar el puerto del servidor de Apache para que no entre en conflicto con el puerto 80 que ya está en uso en tu PC.

Básicamente comenta que se debe **acceder al archivo httpd.conf**, que suele estar en *directorio_donde_está_instalado_Apache/conf* y **cambiar el puerto 80 por el que tu prefieras** (por ejemplo el 8080).

> *Listen 0.0.0.0:80* **cambiarlo por** *Listen 0.0.0.0:**8080***
>
> *Listen [::0]:80* **cambiarlo por** *Listen [::0]:**8080***
>
> *ServerName localhost:80* **cambiarlo por** *ServerName localhost:**8080***

Eso sí, para acceder a todo aquello que desplegues en el Apache, deberás acceder a través de localhost:8080, es decir, debes decirle explícitamente que quieres acceder al puerto 8080. Si no se especifica un puerto, el navegador asume que quieres acceder al 80.

Comment: Buenas, gracias a lo que has puesto soy capaz de iniciar apache, pero en cuanto a lo de acceder explícitamente por el puerto 8080 en el navegador cómo lo haces?

Comment: Debes incluir el puerto después del nombre de dominio. En este caso que expongo arriba sería localhost. Por lo tanto, deberías incluir lo siguiente `localhost:8080`.

Si solo pones localhost en la barra de direcciones del navegador, es como si pusieras `localhost:80`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he tenido este problema muchas veces, y al final, lo mejor ha sido reinstalar todo teniendo en cuenta una serie de consideraciones, te digo:

1. Desinstalar cualquier gestor de servicios anterior.
2. Elimina cualquier carpeta de instalaciones anteriores de XAMPP de C:\ ó
   C:\Program Files
3. **Desactivar Firewall de Windows** u otro firewall que tengamos junto al antivirus.
4. Bajar al mínimo la “Configuración de Control de cuentas de usuario"
5. Descargar xampp-win32- 1.8.1-VC9- installer.exe o posterior (¡¡No utilizar
   otras versiones anteriores o versión Lite!!)
6. Comenzamos la instalación. (Instalar en C:)
7. Cuando concluyamos la instalación, iniciamos los servicios de Apache y MySQL en el Control Panel.
8. Finalmente, los servicios deben de salir en color verde, si todo ha ido bien.

Answer (score 0):

a mi me pasaba que había un proceso que utilizaba el puerto, y por más que cambiara la configuración de xampp no conectaba, me tocaba en este caso dejar xampp con su puerto por defecto e ir al administrador de tareas y buscar allí dicho servicio, en este momento no recuerdo el nombre y no estoy en mi pc, pero es un servicio de sql, revisa, si lo finalizas xampp funciona.

Al menos a mi me sirvió